# undefined error in node.js module

Tags: node.js

I am new in node.js. I have to make run one existing application. When I run the application, I am getting undefined variable for the following code. What can be wrong?

```
var i18n = require("i18n");

module.exports = function(app, express){

var config = this; // "this" is undefined, so I get config undefined which is causing problem ahead.


    app.configure(function(){
       ...
       ...
    });


   .....
   .....

    return config;

};
```

Comment: How are you calling the module function?

Comment: @numbers1311407, In app.js, I have this code to call the module.

`var express = require('express'),
    loader = require('./loader'),
    testHelper,
    testData;

var app = module.exports = express();
var config = require('./config.js')(app, express);
loader.loadConfig(app);`

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), no pun intended.  When calling the function in the way that you are, `this` is not defined.